# I need assistance with my MySql query (selecting from multiple tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, I have 3 tables:

1. **PIZZA** with pizza_ID, pizza_title, and pizza_price
2. **INGREDIENTS** with ingredients_ID; ingredients_title, and ingredients_description
3. **PIZZA_INGREDIENTS** with ID, pizza_id, ingredients_id

and I need to select all pizza_title from PIZZA that contains 2 ingredients.
For now, I have this:

```
SELECT pizza.pizza_ID, pizza.pizza_title, pizza.pizza_price, pizza_ingredients.ingredient_id
FROM pizza
JOIN pizza_ingredients ON pizza_ingredients.pizza_id=pizza.id
WHERE pizza_ingredients.ingredient_id='7' or pizza_ingredients.id='4'
GROUP BY pizza.id
```

this code returns all pizzas that have ingredient 7 or ingredient 4. and I need only pizzas that have both 7 and 4...

SQL is not my strong side, and I appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: just change condition "OR" to "AND"

Comment: @krishnPatel That change will result in zero records, always, because an ingredient ID cannot simultaneously have two different values.

Comment: Id in table 3 is very likely redundant

Comment: than you need to run two different query and join it.

Comment: why are you using or ?you should use AND condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try joining to a subquery which does an aggregation to find all pizzas having exactly two ingredients:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM pizza p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT pizza_id
    FROM pizza_ingredients
    GROUP BY pizza_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) p2
    ON p1.pizza_id = p2.pizza_id;
```

If I misunderstood the wording of your question, and you instead want to find all pizzas having two particular ingredients, without regard to other ingredients, then use this query:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM pizza p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT pizza_id
    FROM pizza_ingredients
    WHERE ingredients_id IN (4, 7)
    GROUP BY pizza_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ingredients_id) = 2
) p2
    ON p1.pizza_id = p2.pizza_id;
```

Comment: don't forget to filter the ingredients: `WHERE pizza_ingredients.ingredients_id IN (7, 4)` otherwise it will display all pizza with only two ingredients.

Comment: Um, I think you've misunderstood

Comment: @JohnWoo That was my reading of the OP.  I gave a second query which I think is what is on your mind.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it should be the second query since the OP mentioned `I need only pizzas that have both 7 and 4...`

Comment: Yeah, you're right...besides it makes no sense to speak of a pizza with only two ingredients.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agree! haha

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did say it wrong... I should say "I need only pizzas that have at least both 7 and 4..." or something. Thanks